# Can single orderer handle mutliple channels?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Can single orderer handle multiple channels?

This is .yaml configuration of orderer:

```
orderer_example_com:
  container_name: orderer.example.com
  image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
  environment:
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis1.block
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/msp
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.key
    - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/server.crt
   - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3/tls/ca.crt]
  working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
  command: orderer
  ports:
    - 7050:7050
  volumes:
    - ./channel:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer
    - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1
    - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2
    - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3
  networks:
    chfn:
      aliases:
       - orderer.example.com
```

I have 1 genesis file for each channel and property ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE is set to just one of them. Should I define orderers for each channel?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look on `configtx.yaml` file which actually includes all relevant information to be encoded into ordering service genesis block, such as the **Organizations** which defines all know organization at the bootstrap stage which might form a consortium to initiate a channel. In fact the `configtxgen` encodes org related crypto material into the genesis block, such that orderer will be able to validate identity of the peers who tries to submit transactions or get connected to deliver new blocks.

```
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp
```

While this genesis block has nothing to do with the genesis block which created with new channel. So to your question one ordering service can able to handle multiple channels as long as they consist of know organizations. You can define profiles for `configtxgen` tool to specify a list of organization to be encoded as consortium for specific channel, for example:

```
Orgs12Channel:                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
```

Defines channel of two organizations `Org1` and `Org2`, whereas

```
Orgs13Channel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org3
```

could define an additional channel of `Org1` and `Org3`. After all the configuration for ordering service which defines consortium and lists all organizations which could define channels.

```
OrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can a single order for multiple channels.
But we should have many orders to keep the system available.

Comment: Ordering service already consist of many orderer nodes, specifically for this reason, while multiple ordering service needed if you would like to achieve greater level of confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR: of @Artem's response is yes, an ordering service in Hyperledger Fabric can handle multiple channels.

The orderer service may have multiple nodes, to provide resilience of the service implemented by some fault tolerant protocol such as PAXOS, RAFT, *BFT, etc. For the Kafka orderer, we currently support crash fault tolerance.

Fabric also supports a topology model that has multiple distinct orderer services, each supporting a non-overlapping set of channels.

Peer nodes can participate in multiple channels, and those channels *may* each be supported by different orderer services.